# How to hide button control in VBA

Tags: ms-access, button, onclick, vba

Is there anybody out here still programming VBA?

I'm trying to get this code to work

```vb
Private Sub button3_click()

    'hide main buttons
    button1.Visible = False
    button2.Visible = False
    button3.Visible = False

    'show submenu buttons
    button4.Visible = True;
    button5.Visible = True;

End Sub
```

What I'm trying to do basically is that I have a main form that has 5 main button controls.  2 of them are hidden on startup.  So when I click button 3, I want to hide the first 3 main buttons, and "unhide" the other two.
When trying to execute this event, I got an error

"**Runtime Error 2165 - You can't hide a control that has the focus**".

Has anybody come across this aspect of programming before?  I'm sure it's doable.  I just don't understand what went wrong here...

Comment: Thanks everyone. All of your suggestions have been tried - they work! I should have thought there's a way to make this simple functionality work, if you could 'think outside the square' when coding. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the focus to one of the visible control, before hiding the current one

```
Private Sub button3_click()

    'show submenu buttons
    button4.Visible = True
    button5.Visible = True

    DoEvents          'execute any pending events, to make sure the button 4 and 5 are really visible
    button4.SetFocus  'change the focus to a now visible control
    DoEvents          'execute any pending events, to make sure that button4 really has the focus

    'now you can hide the other buttons

    'hide main buttons
    button1.Visible = False
    button2.Visible = False
    button3.Visible = False

End Sub
```

Maybe you can skip the DoEvents command, you should try

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought that the error was explicit enough. Move the focus to some control that you are not trying to hide before you run your code. Also, consider `Me` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223099(v=office.11).aspx